# How can I tell the compiler to re execute code at specific point when if statement is true

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn to how to code myself so there're alot of thing that I didn't know.

What I'm trying to do is tell the compiler to re execute the code at specific point when if statement is true

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char name[25];
    char first_name[25];
    char last_name[25];

    printf("Please put in your first name here: ");
    scanf("%s", first_name);
    printf("Please put in your last name here: ");
    scanf("%s", last_name);

    /*If this statement below is true, I want the compiler to execute the code above */

    if (strlen(first_name) > 5 || strlen(last_name) >5)
    {
        printf("Last name or First name is too long!\n");

    }

    printf("Welcome %s %s!", first_name, last_name);


return 0;
```

Comment: Have you learned about loops?

Comment: Read about `do {...`

Comment: Just to clarify, I assume you're using some kind of guide, such as a book, to learn in a guided fashion. Any other method is unsafe, as far as C goes. Which resource or guide are you using to help you avoid the subtle pitfalls of C?

Comment: @autistic I'm using this http://www.learn-c.org as my guide to learn c programming.

Comment: @PhouKiethseng Thanks. Unless you plan on writing code for some Unix kernels (and only writing code for some Unix kernels), learning C will probably be as much a waste of time for you as it was for me, if not more-so... if you do choose to continue learning C, K&R2E is commonly advised. Read it until you come across an exercise, don't move on until you've completed the exercise satisfactorily. If you're not interested in programming kernels (and only kernels), I hear good things about [SICP](http://web.mit.edu/alexmv/6.037/sicp.pdf)...

Comment: @PhouKiethseng I checked that website, and it has numerous factual errors. Whatever you do, don't use it. It says, for example, *"C does not have a boolean type"*...

Comment: @autistic Thanks for the warning. Can you recommend some reliable source? whether it's a book, website....etc.

Comment: @PhouKiethseng Well, given that you appear to be struggling with procedural language structures, and C isn't the language to learn about procedural language structures using, I'd recommend you consider a different language if this is your first. I usually recommend SICP to those who are completely new to programming. Once you're familiar with procedural language structures, K&R2E is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If you're designing a console application, you might want to consider taking user input from the command line arguments. i.e.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc <= 2) {
        fputs("insufficient arguments", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (strlen(argv[1]) > 5) {
        fputs("first name too long", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (strlen(argv[2]) > 5) {
        fputs("last name too long", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Welcome %s %s!", argv[1], argv[2]);
}
```

This form of input feels much more natural; you don't have to worry about array sizes or object lifetime... not to mention the end user gets to enjoy autocomplete and your software will blend into their ecosystem better, too. I'm sure they'd rather press the "up" arrow to fix a typo in their command than re-enter the entire entry... if you plan on having users, that is... the console doesn't have many, and those who do enjoy highly scriptable software; they'll write their own alternative if you do a poor job.

If you're not convinced, and you still want to use `scanf`, you need to:

- check the return value
- bring the input stream to a sanitary state after invalid input
- (usually it's best to) read and handle errors for one field at a time

**Check the return value**
The return value for `scanf` is the number of objects successfully matched and assigned to, or `EOF` in the case of some read failure. If the input is not of the format described by your format string, you might get some kind of *match failure*, and `scanf` returns. This is particularly troublesome for numeric directives and `%[`scanset`]` directives, both of which commonly fail when users make some mistake, which is why it's necessary to bring the input stream to a sanitary state after invalid input.

**Bring the input stream to a sanitary state after invalid input**
This is done by reading and discarding characters from the stream until we reach some state where the input might successfully match the format string. We could discard one character and try again, for example, or keep discarding until a whitespace is encountered (e.g. `scanf("%*[^ ]");`). I tend to discard until a newline is encountered (see example below) to mimic the functionality of using `fgets`+`sscanf` (this is another option, btw, but you might still need to bring the stream to some sanitary state if you don't get a full line).

Matching multiple fields with one call increases the complexity of error handling. For each field after the first, we must perform the sanitation step and resume matching, which makes our code more bulky and repetitive, something we seek to eliminate. Nonetheless, here's a brief example of trying to read two fields with one call:

```
void example_1() {
    int x, y;
    switch (scanf("%d %d", &x, &y)) {
        case EOF: exit(0);
        case 0: scanf("%*[^\n]"); example();
        case 1: for (;;) { // x assigned, y uninitialised
                     scanf("%*[ ]");
                     switch (scanf("%d", &y)) {
                         case EOF: exit(0);
                         case 0: continue;
                     }
                }
         }
    }
```

The more fields, the more nested `switch`es. It's easy to see that this is a terrible way to read two fields, let alone three. Perhaps something like this would be appropriate, per field:

```
do {
    fputs("Please enter your first name: ", stdout);
    if (scanf("%24s", first_name) != 1) {
        fputs("(most probably) I/O error", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
} while (strlen(first_name) > 5 && (fputs("First name too long", stderr),
                                    scanf("%*[^\n]") == 0));
```

This really only skims the surface of *a topic that has dragons* in ***a language that has dragons***, which should be a red flag in a red flag to you. If you're not reading a book, or you don't have Kernighan & the late Ritchie themselves (or some professor roughly as reputable) as your professors, then you should get something like that... `scanf` has too many subtle nuances to just *guess* your way around it.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate that. However, I'm too amateur to understand that. I only know just a tiny fraction of c language so your answer is too complicated for me to understand.

Comment: @PhouKiethseng "too amateur to understand that" ... What is *that* exactly? If you tell me what precise words you're struggling with, I can help you. Otherwise, as I mentioned earlier, C probably isn't the language for you right now. It's kind of like learning chemistry when you don't yet understand basic mathematics...

Comment: @Neil then you've commented in the wrong place and I'd request you delete your comment and rewrite it as a comment for the question. However, then it appears as an answer in a comment, a link-only answer to be specific, which is frowned upon. I think your article doesn't actually have "more details", and probably has the wrong attitude anyway; if we avoid everything that has dragons we have no fire, no tools, no tech... and this article suggests avoiding something. Why not just suggest avoiding C, if C has so many pitfalls? ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use term **Loop** instead of **re-execute**..
Here, in your problem you can use looping statements like do-while loop.
Or else we have other method using jump statements.(goto in this case).
Below is your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char name[25];
    char first_name[25];
    char last_name[25];

input:
     printf("Please put in your first name here: ");
     scanf("%24s", first_name);
     printf("Please put in your last name here: ");
     scanf("%24s", last_name);
     /*here %24s is used to specify the size of the buffer i.e 24
     So if you give a string more than 24 characters then %24s takes only   
     24 characters then rest is ignored */

/*If this statement below is true, I want the compiler to execute the code above */

     if (strlen(first_name) > 5 || strlen(last_name) >5)
     {
         printf("Last name or First name is too long!\n");
         goto input;
     }

      printf("Welcome %s %s!", first_name, last_name);
      return 0;
}
```

But usage of goto statements are not recommended because they make logic complex 
Now, you try using do-while loop.

Comment: If you didn't have `scanf` `%s` in there, I'd upvote this answer.

Comment: Okay thanks, I think i understand it now. Btw, since I'm completely new to the coding world and currently use online guide to learn how to code, I wanna know If there's effective way to learn how to code. I'm about to enter freshman year in college as a software engineer so I thought I spent my spare time to learn coding.

Comment: Do not advice poor programming habits like `goto`. DV-ed

Comment: I did quote that **it is not recommended** .I just gave him a method and let him try with other method so that he can learn on own. That why people say **self-learning is best learning**